# How much time past sunrise is it safe to sleep again?

Tags: sandhyavandanam, tamasic

It is said that one should not sleep during sunrise. Suppose I was awake all night for study, job, mahashivratri or whatever. I stayed awake during sunrise and after the sunrise I decide to sleep. **How much time past sunrise can I go to bed so that I get no ill effects or least ill effects (like lethargy, tamas)?**

The only advice I found till now is by Shri radhavallabh shri harivansh ji i.e. You can sleep again if it has been 48 minutes since sunrise.
[link here](https://www.instagram.com/reel/Cq-FLAwuAk7/?igshid=MzRlODBiNWFlZA==)

[This Islam thread](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2717) also discusses the same thing, it says that after the sunrise they can sleep when they like.
But the sandhya kala lasts for 20/24/48 minutes after the sunrise according to various sources. How many minutes should I wait to go to bed after sunrise?